# TypeError: string indices must be integers in django

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x

I am trying to store json into bigchainDB. But problem is when I am hard coding the json object and broadcasting among other nodes Its getting successful. But when I am sending the same json object from the postman I am getting an error `string indices must be integers`

This is my func

```
 def index(request):
    root = settings.BIGCHAINDB
    bdb = BigchainDB(root)
    alice, bob = generate_keypair(), generate_keypair()
    insertDB =  json.dumps(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    jsonDict =  json.loads(insertDB)
    prepared_token_tx = bdb.transactions.prepare(
        operation='CREATE',
        signers=alice.public_key,
        recipients=[([bob.public_key], 10)],
        asset=jsonDict)
    fulfilled_token_tx = bdb.transactions.fulfill(
        prepared_token_tx,
        private_keys=alice.private_key)
    bdb.transactions.send_commit(fulfilled_token_tx)
    txid = fulfilled_token_tx['id']
    return HttpResponse(txid)
```

JSON OBJECT :

> {"data" : {
>     "cphNumber": "321",
>     "farmName": "313",
>     "addressLine1": "13",
>     "addressLine2": "13",
>     "region": "13",
>     "postalCode": "13",
>     "corrName": "13",
>     "corrAddressLine1": "131",
>     "corrAddressLine2": "31",
>     "corrRegion": "31",
>     "corrCountry": "321",
>     "corrPostal": "31",
>     "corrMobile": "321",
>     "corrEmail": "31",
>     "agentName": "31",
>     "agentAddressLine1": "313",
>     "agentAddressLine2": "132",
>     "agentRegion": "13",
>     "agentCountry": "132",
>     "agentPostal": "132",
>     "brn": "13",
>     "animalSpecies": "132"
>   } }

```html
Django Version: 2.1.7
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'api']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/Desktop/blockchain/api/views.py" in index
  48.   asset=jsonDict)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bigchaindb_driver/driver.py" in prepare
  254.             inputs=inputs,

File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bigchaindb_driver/offchain.py" in prepare_transaction
  132.         inputs=inputs,

File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/functools.py" in wrapper
  824.         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bigchaindb_driver/offchain.py" in _prepare_create_transaction_dispatcher
  45.     return prepare_create_transaction(**kwargs)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bigchaindb_driver/offchain.py" in prepare_create_transaction
  196.         asset=asset['data'] if asset else None,

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/
Exception Value: string indices must be integers
```

Any suggestion is most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question and fix the code indentation.

Comment: @KlausD. Its something with the POST request which I am sending the Data because when in place of jsonDict I am directly writing the object its working fine. In my case `jsonDict` object

Comment: Where's the traceback? And what's this `dumps` / `loads` about?

Comment: @KlausD. Question updated

Comment: I think I am getting this error because when I am passing the data through Postman I am passing as json object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using `json.dumps()` on `request.body`, which is already a string. So when you use `json.loads()` on this, your data doesn't get parsed into a `dict`.

```
 def index(request):
    root = settings.BIGCHAINDB
    bdb = BigchainDB(root)
    alice, bob = generate_keypair(), generate_keypair()
    insertDB =  request.body.decode("utf-8")  # Don't use json.dumps() here
    jsonDict =  json.loads(insertDB)
    prepared_token_tx = bdb.transactions.prepare(
        operation='CREATE',
        signers=alice.public_key,
        recipients=[([bob.public_key], 10)],
        asset=jsonDict)
    fulfilled_token_tx = bdb.transactions.fulfill(
        prepared_token_tx,
        private_keys=alice.private_key)
    bdb.transactions.send_commit(fulfilled_token_tx)
    txid = fulfilled_token_tx['id']
    return HttpResponse(txid)
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body)